# C++ "No matching constructor for initialization of" compiler error

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a class which I try to initialize but get the error "No matching constructor for initialization of 'TextureCoordinates'";

Class which I'm trying to initialize:

```
class TextureCoordinates
{
public:
    TextureCoordinates(){};
    TextureCoordinates(Point2D& origin, Dimensions2D& dim);
    Point2D getOrigin() const {return origin;};
    Dimensions2D getDim() const {return dim;};
private:
    Point2D origin;
    Dimensions2D dim;
};
```

Line with compiler error:

```
TextureCoordinates result(point, Dimensions2D(width, height));
```

Definition of constructor:

```
TextureCoordinates::TextureCoordinates(Point2D& origin, Dimensions2D& dim):
origin(origin), dim(dim) {}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where's the definition of the constructor? All I see is the declaration.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your constructor takes the arguments by non-const reference, but you pass a temporary object (`Dimensions2D(width, height)`) to it. Temporaries, even non-const ones, do not bind to non-const references.

Solution, make your constructor take const references (it shouldn't modify the passed objects anyway):

```
TextureCoordinates(Point2D const& origin, Dimensions2D const& dim);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
TextureCoordinates result(point, Dimensions2D(width, height))
```

The second parameter is an rvalue that cannot be bound to lvalue reference the constructor expects:

```
TextureCoordinates(Point2D& origin, Dimensions2D& dim);
```

You can fix it by changing the signature of the constructor to

```
TextureCoordinates(Point2D& origin, const Dimensions2D& dim);
TextureCoordinates(Point2D& origin, Dimensions2D&& dim); // alternative for c++11
```

(if you can)
or making the parameter a variable

```
Dimension2D dim=Dimensions2D(width, height);
TextureCoordinates result(point, dim)
```

Answer (score 1):

Temporary variables cannot be passed as a reference in C++ because then you can change the value of a temporary object in the function that is soon going to disappear!! No such problem exists for reference to constants.....
So your function definition should be like

```
TextureCoordinates(Point2D const& origin, Dimensions2D const& dim);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare Dimensions2d outside.

```
Dimension2d d(width, height);
TextureCoordinates result(point, d);
```

Answer (score -1):

did you write the implementation of :

```
TextureCoordinates(Point2D& origin, Dimensions2D& dim);
```